# "An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request" with ABP asp.net core 3.1

Tags: abp

I have just set up the ABP code in the machine and when I run the web project, I am getting this issue.

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(string host, int port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(string host, int port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing
SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(string host, int port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Show raw exception details
HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(string host, int port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable<TResult>+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, bool allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable<TResult>+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable<TResult>+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable<TResult>+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, bool doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Polly.Retry.AsyncRetryEngine.ImplementationAsync<TResult>(Func<Context, CancellationToken, Task<TResult>> action, Context context, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ExceptionPredicates shouldRetryExceptionPredicates, ResultPredicates<TResult> shouldRetryResultPredicates, Func<DelegateResult<TResult>, TimeSpan, int, Context, Task> onRetryAsync, int permittedRetryCount, IEnumerable<TimeSpan> sleepDurationsEnumerable, Func<int, DelegateResult<TResult>, Context, TimeSpan> sleepDurationProvider, bool continueOnCapturedContext)
Polly.AsyncPolicy<TResult>.ExecuteAsync(Func<Context, CancellationToken, Task<TResult>> action, Context context, CancellationToken cancellationToken, bool continueOnCapturedContext)
Microsoft.Extensions.Http.PolicyHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task<HttpResponseMessage> sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, bool disposeCts)
Volo.Abp.Http.Client.DynamicProxying.ApiDescriptionFinder.GetApiDescriptionFromServerAsync(HttpClient client, string baseUrl)
Volo.Abp.Http.Client.DynamicProxying.ApiDescriptionCache.GetAsync(string baseUrl, Func<Task<ApplicationApiDescriptionModel>> factory)
Volo.Abp.Http.Client.DynamicProxying.ApiDescriptionFinder.GetApiDescriptionAsync(HttpClient client, string baseUrl)
Volo.Abp.Http.Client.DynamicProxying.ApiDescriptionFinder.FindActionAsync(HttpClient client, string baseUrl, Type serviceType, MethodInfo method)
Volo.Abp.Http.Client.DynamicProxying.DynamicHttpProxyInterceptor<TService>.MakeRequestAsync(IAbpMethodInvocation invocation)
Volo.Abp.Http.Client.DynamicProxying.DynamicHttpProxyInterceptor<TService>.MakeRequestAndGetResultAsync<T>(IAbpMethodInvocation invocation)
Volo.Abp.Http.Client.DynamicProxying.DynamicHttpProxyInterceptor<TService>.GetResultAsync(Task task, Type resultType)
Volo.Abp.Http.Client.DynamicProxying.DynamicHttpProxyInterceptor<TService>.InterceptAsync(IAbpMethodInvocation invocation)
Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAsyncAbpInterceptorAdapter<TInterceptor>.InterceptAsync<TResult>(IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo, Func<IInvocation, IInvocationProceedInfo, Task<TResult>> proceed)
Castle.DynamicProxy.AsyncInterceptorBase.ProceedAsynchronous<TResult>(IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo)
Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAbpMethodInvocationAdapterWithReturnValue<TResult>.ProceedAsync()
Volo.Abp.Validation.ValidationInterceptor.InterceptAsync(IAbpMethodInvocation invocation)
Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAsyncAbpInterceptorAdapter<TInterceptor>.InterceptAsync<TResult>(IInvocation invocation, IInvocationProceedInfo proceedInfo, Func<IInvocation, IInvocationProceedInfo, Task<TResult>> proceed)
Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.Client.CachedApplicationConfigurationClient.<GetAsync>b__13_0()
Volo.Abp.Caching.DistributedCache<TCacheItem, TCacheKey>.GetOrAddAsync(TCacheKey key, Func<Task<TCacheItem>> factory, Func<DistributedCacheEntryOptions> optionsFactory, Nullable<bool> hideErrors, CancellationToken token)
Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.Client.CachedApplicationConfigurationClient.GetAsync()
Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.Client.RemoteLanguageProvider.GetLanguagesAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.RequestLocalization.DefaultAbpRequestLocalizationOptionsProvider.GetLocalizationOptionsAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.RequestLocalization.AbpRequestLocalizationMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass5_1+<<UseMiddlewareInterface>b__1>d.MoveNext()
Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.MultiTenancy.MultiTenancyMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass5_1+<<UseMiddlewareInterface>b__1>d.MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Tracing.AbpCorrelationIdMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass5_1+<<UseMiddlewareInterface>b__1>d.MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: How did you download the template? Which options did you set? (Angular, tirered etc.)

Comment: Tiered MVC core template

Answer (score 0):

Run projects in this order: *.IdentiyServer project, *.HttpApi.Host project and then *.Web project.

Comment: Did it but still the same with web project.

Comment: When I set the identity project, I am getting a page with login button but when I click on it, it keeps on loading but nothing happens.

Comment: I did the same, (using Blazor ) but getting the same error and I followed the run projects order...last project the Blazor (web interface) has error.